# How do I index owner/group by path and apply them later?

Tags: bash, find, paste

My goal here is to run through the whole filesystem and grab the absolute path, file owner, and file group and store them in a file for later use with a script to re-apply ownership on "known" files.

Note: Requires 'acl' package be installed.

Here's what I have so far:

```
find / -exec ./fileog.sh {} \;
```

Contents of ./fileog.sh:

```
getfacl -R "$2" | awk 'NR==1, NR==3 {print $3}' | paste -s -d ',' >> ./ogindex.txt
```

The problem is, I get the following error:

```
getfacl: : No such file or directory
```

but if I just do this, it works:

```
find / -exec getfacl -R "$2" {} \;
```

try this yourself :)

```
getfacl -R ./some.file | awk 'NR==1, NR==3 {print $3}' | paste -s -d ','
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Shouldn't your `getfacl` call in `fileog.sh` be `getfacl -R "$1"` instead of `getfacl -R "$2"`? You're only passing in one argument...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using both `find` and `getfacl -R`, or you should use them more carefully.

`find` already recurses, so you're hitting each file multiple times this way.

I would solve the problem this way:

```
find / -exec stat -c '%n,%U,%G' {} \; >> ./ogindex.txt
```

If you need leading `/` stripped this would be a tiny bit of post processing.

Note: Presumes `stat` which supports formatting via `-c`; not all versions of `stat` are alike.

Also, I strongly recommend that you do not store this information in this format. What happens if a file name has a comma in it? If you use `user,group,filename` it's safer, because you can just treat everything after the second comma as the file name. This is still vulnerable to crafted file names, of course.

Comment: Thank you so very much! This is so much cleaner with just a 1 liner!

Comment: This also has the side-effect of running *much* faster. In about half of the run time of the old I'm already past the point it was at.

Comment: @Nobody: Want to be *even faster*? If you don't require any post-processing, replace `\;` with `+`. This has the effect of passing multiple files to `stat`, which saves some overhead.

Comment: Just for reference, a trivial benchmark on one of my boxes shows that `stat`ing `/etc/` with `\;` takes 18 seconds, but with `+` it takes only `0.447` seconds. And yes, that's with everything cached.

Answer (score 2):

You run `fileog.sh` in `find` and give him only one argument (filename, `{}`):

```
-exec ./fileog.sh {} \;
```

This filename will be accessible inside the script as `$1`, not `$2`.

You must write `$1` instead of `$2` in the script, or you must add the missing argument to te script in `-exec`.

Fragment of `ogeindex.txt`:

```
etc,root,root
etc/ucf.conf,root,root
etc/gshadow,root,shadow
etc/sudoers.d,root,root
etc/sudoers.d/README,root,root
etc/motd.tail,root,root
```

Comment: Thank you for catching that silly mistake! Now if I run

`find / -exec ./fileog.sh {} \;`

only errors are outputted. But if I specify and absolute path (or wildcard) into `find', it'll work properly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: yes, it must be so; `find` executes `./fileog.sh` for each file it has found and doesn't print its name. The script is executed anyway. But if you want to print names of file that were found also, just add `-print` before `-exec`: `-print -exec ... \;`

Comment: correct, but ./fileog.sh should print the name as the first line of output: `# file: /boot/initrd.img`

Comment: @Nobody: added example of output